# Can't make image as a link

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, hyperlink

I am using `asp:Hyperlink` controls to generate an image as a link.

Below is the aspx code and C# code.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="mainInteractiveFileLink" runat="server">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

### C#

```
mainInteractiveFileLink.NavigateUrl = thisMainInteractiveItem.linkURL;
mainInteractiveFileLink.ImageUrl    = thisMainInteractiveItem.imageFile;
```

I want to make the image as a link. I have tried other options like `<a>`,`<image>` HTML controls and `imagebutton`.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Code in question provides the answer to the question (assuming correct values are passed to methods). It is very unclear what kind of help you expect without good [MCVE] and explanation of how code does not work. Note that for HTML questions showing resulting HTML markup and browser console errors is generally good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your image under your Hyperlink control:

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="mainInteractiveFileLink" runat="server">
  <asp:image id="img" runat="server" />
</asp:Hyperlink>
```

Code Behind:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com";
HyperLink1.ImageUrl = "http://assets.fodors.com/destinations/2869/tower-bridge-london-england_main.jpg";
```

And generated HTML:

```
<a id="mainInteractiveFileLink" href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="http://assets.fodors.com/destinations/2869/tower-bridge-london-england_main.jpg" >
</a>
```

Based on your code, you are generating your linkURL on your image control.

Comment: sorry mate, It doesnt work i have tried this before as well. This is what it renders <div class="slide active" style="position: absolute; left: 1920px; width: 1920px;">
                        <a id="ctl00_OverSizeContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_MainInteractiveMainRepeater_ctl01_mainInteractiveFileLink" href="../Promotion/Split">    <img id="ctl00_OverSizeContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_MainInteractiveMainRepeater_ctl01_img" src="www.xyz.com/SharedContent/pjjp-qXPy06uyo8WW5hzFw.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">  </a>
                    </div>

Comment: You want your image to be clickable and direct to URL right?

Comment: yes exactly but I know normally above code works but its not working in this case.

Comment: Thanks Willy, I understand your point. I just redone the page to do the same thing. It is working fine now. I really appreciate your time and efforts.